# Execute different NSDocument subclass according to file extensions

Tags: xcode, nsdocument

I have written different parsers and different NSDocument subclasses for files with different extensions to visualize the data. I would like to intergrate them together into one application. I am using NSDocument architecture. I am not sure how to map files identified by file extensions to its NSdocument object.

I have tried to add document types in the Xcode info session with class and extensions. However, it seems that it always execute the same parser regardless of the file's extension. [image]

Answer (score 0):

1)Subclass NSDocumentController

a)in your XIB with mainmenu put a new object and give it a class of your new NSDocumentController subclass

or

b)create a new instance before appDidFinishLaunching (initialize, load...)

2)override methods as you see on picture (those which determine type and return document instances) to provide new document instances (as per type)

[image: Document]

Read more [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocBasedAppProgrammingGuideForOSX/AdvancedTopics/AdvancedTopics.html)

Also scan with your eyes NSDocumentController.h (CMD+SHIFT+O and type NSDoc...)